# Matriz inversa em forma de blocos

Tags: matriz, matemática

Tenho uma matriz 1 de forma (X e U são quadradas):

```
| X Y |
| Z U |
```

Que é a inversa da matriz (que eu não conheço) (A e D são quadradas):

```
| A B |
| C D |
```

Estou tentando conseguir o matriz inversa de "A", a partir da matriz 1, tentei usar "Matrix inversion in block form", mas só consigo:

> - `A-1 * B = Y * U^-1`
> - `C * A^-1 = Z * U^-1`

Será possível achar só `A^-1` sem ter que inverter a matriz 1?

[matinv](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~jang/book/addenda/matinv/matinv/matinv.html)

Comment: Jorge, este site é voltado a programação, sua duvida nao parece ser relativa a programação, e sim, matematica.